# Static website (S3 Bucket) with Google login (Authorization)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm looking to host a static website gated by Google login.

This website should be accessible only by people on my company logged with emails @mydomain.ca and @mydomain.com.

I have a bitbucket pipeline that works this way: when new content is merged in master branch, it builds static files and send it to S3 Bucket.

I have access to the following AWS solutions: Lambda, S3, Cloudfront, Cognito, Lambda@Edge.

I'm afraid that im thinking an overkill solution... it will be used by around 40 people/day. Any suggestions will be appreciated.